# Why is GetSystemTimes #if'd out of winbase.h?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

So, the declaration of `GetSystemTimes` in `winbase.h` (on my machine, Windows 7 VS2005)

```
#if _WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0501

BOOL
WINAPI
GetSystemTimes(
    __out_opt LPFILETIME lpIdleTime,
    __out_opt LPFILETIME lpKernelTime,
    __out_opt LPFILETIME lpUserTime
    );

#endif
```

Sure, I can just `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501`, but that just doesn't seem right and I can't find an explanation of why this is the case and what my alternatives are.  Anyone have some insight here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `#if`ed out because it wasn't added to the API until Windows NT v5.01, AKA Windows XP.  Your program is expected to `#define` the symbol `_WIN32_WINNT` to the hex value of your minimum targeted Windows version: see [Using the Windows Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you don't define `_WIN32_WINNT`, it assumes you're targeting the lowest common denominator, and it doesn't provide newer API features.  So if you want to use them, you need to define `_WIN32_WINNT` to an appropriate value and understand that your code won't run on older versions of Windows, which is usually fine -- nobody's going to complain that your code doesn't run on Windows 98.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that now.  I'm not a big WinAPI guy, so definining (what I initially thought to be) the OS version just seemed... bad.  Now I understand it, so it makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

According to [MSDN documentation,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#setting_winver_or__win32_winnt) the possibility you mentioned is the intended usage.  Although I agree with you that it can seem odd, this way of doing things lets you build projects targeting platforms with different minimum operating system versions, so you aren't surprised when a Windows API function isn't available on the target machine.

Comment: Yep, didn't find that page.  It just feels so wrong to define that... but whatever, it works.

Answer (score -1):

`GetSystemTimes()` Declared in `Winbase.h`

```
#if _WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0501           // look at this

BOOL
WINAPI
GetSystemTimes(
    LPFILETIME lpIdleTime,
    LPFILETIME lpKernelTime,
    LPFILETIME lpUserTime
    );

#endif // (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0501)
```

use the include like this :

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <Windows.h>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. "Sure, I can just `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501`, but that just doesn't seem right" -- the asker is aware that this is an option. The question is _why_ it's like that.